# battery charging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I have:

-12V 7.2Ah,sealed lead battery,valve regulated
-solar panel 12v with 100mA

my question is,how long does it take to charge this battery by using this solar panel?

Comment: The battery "contains" 7200mAh when it is full. So if it is totally discharged you would need at least 7200mAh/100mA = 72 hours. That becomes even more depending on your charging circuit, solar conditions etc.

Comment: 12V from the solar panel won't charge the battery very well. You need a higher voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Measure open circuit panel voltage in bright sunlight - ideally will be 17V or more.

And/or count "cells" in panel  - usually 36 series cells for a 12V lead acid charger suited panel.

Check current - put DMM etc on 200 mA range or Amps range and measure panel short circuit current into meter. This should be say 100 ma+ for 100 mA panel

Full sun hours to charge ~= 7200 / Ichg mA.
0r 7200/100 =~~~ 72 hours in your case.

Equivalent full sun hours are much less than hours of daylight.

Google

```
     gaisma  your_city_name
```

and read kWh/m^2/day figure from table to see how many SSH (sunshine hour/day) are available at your site.  6 SSh/day is high in Summer.
So you would need about 7200/100/6 = 12 days in mid summer to charge the battery completely.